# Ubuntu 16.04 wont reboot after update (black/purple screen)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, updates

I have a Asus X555Q and recently I updated Ubuntu with the software updater. Once it was completed I rebooted my computer and Ubuntu stalled at the black/purple screen and then nothing is happening.

I tried a lot of things and read other thread about this but nothing solved my problem.

if its help, my computer is dual boot with window and ubuntu. If you need more information I'll gladly give it to you.

thanks for your help

Comment: 16.10 is beyond end of life a.d no lo ger supported

Comment: I see you removed any reference to 16.10 from the question. Was it a typo, or?

Comment: Yes I thought it was 16.10 but I am on 16.04 and I did the update that the software updater offered me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)